# How can I remove the "embed preview" that appears before loading an embedded item in SharePoint?

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, embed, sharepoint-online

I have an embedded item on my SharePoint site and while it loads there is a message that shows a broken image and then the words "embed preview". It only shows for a few seconds and then goes away but I was wondering if there was a way to remove this?

[embed preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYbwb.png)

Comment: If you want to delete this damaged content, you can directly edit the page and delete the Embed Web Part. Or edit this web part and delete this data source. Or you provide more information about the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your console, you will be able that embed webpart does a Graph request to the DriveItem of this embedded file to retrieve the thumbnail of this file. The Thumbnail is used as Preview in your embedded webpart and also for previewing files in the list library.

For instance:

```
https://{{tenantName}}.sharepoint.com/sites/{{siteName}}/_api/v2.1/sites/{{siteId}}/items/{{itemId}}/driveItem/thumbnails/0/{{size}}/content?prefer=noRedirect
```

Below you can find all the files that supports preview:

[File types supported for previewing files in OneDrive, SharePoint, and Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-types-supported-for-previewing-files-in-onedrive-sharepoint-and-teams-e054cd0f-8ef2-4ccb-937e-26e37419c5e4)

As you can see, .aspx files extensions supports preview. However; If you upload a .aspx file without creating it using OOTB features in SharePoint, it will not create a thumbnail and will make this request return a 404 - Not found. And then, once you load the page in your embed webpart, it will return as broken image in the preview because the thumbnail doesn't exist.

There's an workaround to delete the thumbnail immediately when your embed content is being loaded but, you can only achieve this by using a custom JavaScript in the page that is rendering the embed webpart. To add a custom JavaScript in your page, you will need to have the **[Modern Script Editor Webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-script-editor/README.md)**.

Once you deploy the package, set it to be available in your site.

When available, add the Modern Script Editor Webpart in the page that you are using your embed webpart and use the following JavaScript code:

```
<script>
// Function to remove the img element
function removeImage() {
    var img = document.querySelector('img[alt="Embed Preview."]');
    if (img) {
        img.remove();
    }
}

// Setting up the MutationObserver
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            // Check if the added node is the desired img element or contains the desired img element
            for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                var node = mutation.addedNodes[i];
                if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { // Check that this is an element node
                    if (node.tagName === 'IMG' && node.getAttribute('alt') === 'Embed Preview.') {
                        node.remove();
                    } else if (node.querySelector('img[alt="Embed Preview."]')) { // Check its descendants
                        removeImage();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

var targetElement = document.querySelector("#spPageCanvasContent");
// Start observing the document with the configured parameters
observer.observe(targetElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });


</script>
```

This script will use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe when a change has ocurred in the element ID `spPageCanvasContent`. This element is basically the content of your SharePoint page.

Now, once the embed content is loaded, you will not see the broken preview. I had the same issue as you and it worked for me.

**Note:** In my case, I only have the embed webpart that changes in the content of the page. If you have several components that changes in your page, you might need to limit the scope of the `MutationObserver` to avoid performance issues. To limit the scope of the changes, change the element of the `querySelector` in the line below:

```
var targetElement = document.querySelector("#spPageCanvasContent");
```